# How do I find the index of an element in a table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's say I have this code:

```lua
local testtbl = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
```

How do I get the index of an element?
For example:

```lua
print(indexOf(testtbl, "bar")) -- 2
```

Comment: @Aki i answered my own question, q&a-style, i kind of know

Comment: If you know and there is already answer on SO, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the table with `ipairs`, like so:

```lua
function indexOf(tbl, value)
    for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
        if v == value then
            return i
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Note: This will only work if `tbl` is a sequence (has only consecutive integer keys starting at 1). I'd probably use `pairs` for a more general solution which will still work for sequences.